# How do I match email to key which I am entering in form so it knows which email the key belongs to later echo on another page through session in php?

Tags: php

```
 <?php
session_start();
include 'dbConnect.php';
$email = '';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$json = '{"false":"telegramlogin.php","a":"user.php","b":"user.php","c":"admin.php"}';// data pro výběr přesměrování

// vstup do rozhrani---------------------------------------------------------------
if(isset($_REQUEST['telegram_key']) && $_REQUEST['telegram_key']){
$redirects = telegram($_REQUEST['telegram_key'], $json, $db);
header('Location: '.$redirects);
exit;
}

elseif(isset($_REQUEST['new_key'])){

   new_pass($db,$email);
}

else{
  echo 'Authentication failure';
}


//konec vstupu ---------------------------------------------------------------------
//this is the new function I am trying to make
function new_pass($db,$email){

  $redirects = json_decode($json,true);
  $tmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM change_pass WHERE telegram_key=:tg_key AND time < :tm" );
  $tmp->execute(array('tg_key'=>$telegram_key, 'tm'=>time()));
  $data = $tmp->fetch();

 }

 //this is the function I am basing it on
 function telegram($telegram_key, $json, $db){
 $redirects = json_decode($json, true);
 $tmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM telegram_log WHERE telegram_key=:tg_key
 AND time < :tm");

$tmp->execute(array('tg_key'=>$telegram_key, 'tm'=>time()));
$data = $tmp->fetch();
if($data){
$tmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM operators WHERE operator_id=:op_id");
$tmp->execute(array('op_id'=>$data[0]));
$operator = $tmp->fetch();
if($operator){
  if(!set_my_sessions($operator, $db)){  // neco je spatne z funkce set_my_sessions
 return $redirects['false'];  
  }
  return $redirects[$operator['users']]."?err=3";// vyber presmerovani

 }
 }
 return $redirects['false'];// neco je spatne
 exit;
 }
 function set_my_sessions(array $operator, $db){
 $tmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company_id = :comp_id");
 $tmp->execute(array('comp_id'=>$operator['company_id']));
 $company = $tmp->fetchAll();
 if($company){
 $_SESSION['login']['operator_id'] = $operator['operator_id'];
 $_SESSION['login']['company_id'] = $operator['company_id'];
 $_SESSION['login']['user_type'] = $operator['operator_title'];
 $_SESSION['login']['token'] = $company[0]['token'];
 $_SESSION['login']['operator_token'] = $operator['auth_key'];
 $_SESSION['login']['operator_name'] = $operator['operator_name'];
 $_SESSION['login']['online_photo'] = $operator['online_avatar'];
 if(isset($operator['users'])){
 $_SESSION['login']['users'] = $operator['users'];
 } else if(!isset($operator['users'])) {
 $_SESSION['login']['users']='c';
 }

if($operator['users'] == 'a'){
$_SESSION['administrace']='admin';
} else if($operator['users'] == 'b') {
$_SESSION['administrace']='lead';
} else if($operator['users'] == 'c'){
$_SESSION['administrace']='adv';
} else if( is_null($operator['users'])){
$_SESSION['administrace']='adv';
}

setcookie("tmp_operator_id", $_SESSION['login']['operator_id'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_company_id", $_SESSION['login']['company_id'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_user_type", $_SESSION['login']['user_type'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_oper_token", $_SESSION['login']['operator_token'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_token", $_SESSION['login']['token'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_users", $operator['users'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_name", $operator['operator_name'], time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("tmp_online_photo", $operator['online_avatar'], time()+3600, "/");  

setcookie("operator_id", $_SESSION['login']['operator_id'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("company_id", $_SESSION['login']['company_id'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("user_type", $operator['operator_title'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("oper_token", $operator['auth_key'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("token", $company[0]['token'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("name", $operator['operator_name'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("users", $operator['users'], time() + (86400*30), "/");
setcookie("online_photo", $operator['online_avatar'], time() + (86400*30),
"/");
return true;
}
else
 return false;
}


?>
```

sorry for this not too perfect formatting
I enter token>token gets matched to an email without having to enter it into the form>Redirects me to another page if exists and echo session email on the new page

```
function new_pass($db,$email){

$redirects = json_decode($json,true);
$tmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM change_pass WHERE telegram_key=:tg_key AND time < :tm" );
$tmp->execute(array('tg_key'=>$telegram_key, 'tm'=>time()));
$data = $tmp->fetch();


if($_SESSION['email'] == $email){
  //echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

}

How should I write the query that would do it?

This is my first project and its important for me to get it done.

Comment: there is very much code in your question. can you reduce it to a smaller examples to show what you mean? and some description of how those two scripts relate to each other (it's quite unclear)

Comment: @Jakumi I figured it out, going to update my post with how it was supposed to be. :D